# SpringCloud Gateway redirect based on URL and Method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Springboot : 2.0.4.RELEASE

I am using Swagger documentation to create `RouteDefincationLocator` to redirect my incoming request to appropriate service in Spring.

Now there are some services who has same URL with different http method name. i.e

1. `POST /v1/orders` (This is more restricted then other url)
2. `GET /v1/orders?view=single`

Now in Spring cloud gateway I want to apply 2 different set of filter on each URL

i.e.

**For : POST /v1/orders**

Filters

1. ValidUser
2. Has Create Permission

**For : GET /v1/orders?view=single**

Filters

1. ValidUser

I have implemented **RouteDefinitionLocator**, and implemented method

```
public Flux<RouteDefinition> getRouteDefinitions()
```

I have also set predicates **PredicateDefinition** but this is only verifying URL Path and not method

There are lots of consumer of these services, so I can not change the URL

Can someone tell me how can I add different filters based on incomming **URL**+**Method**

Thanks in advance.